# Error raised while creating the trigger in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Compilation failed, line 3 (14:38:54) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong typeCompilation failed, line 3 (14:38:54) The line numbers associated with compilation errors are relative to the first BEGIN statement. This only affects the compilation of database triggers.
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

```
CREATE TABLE  "P1_EXAM_TIMETABLE" 
   (    "EXAM_ID" NUMBER(7,0), 
    "SCH_NO" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "CLASS_CODE" VARCHAR2(3) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "EXAM_NAME" VARCHAR2(11) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "MAX_MARKS" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "EXAM_DATE" DATE, 
    "SCH_SESSION" VARCHAR2(7) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "SUBJECT" VARCHAR2(20) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "CREATED_BY" VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "CREATED_ON" NUMBER, 
    "UPDATED_BY" VARCHAR2(30) COLLATE "USING_NLS_COMP", 
    "UPDATED_ON" NUMBER, 
     CONSTRAINT "P1_EXAM_TIMETABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EXAM_ID")
  USING INDEX  ENABLE
   )  DEFAULT COLLATION "USING_NLS_COMP"
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  BI_P1_EXAM_TIMETABLE BEFORE
INSERT ON P1_EXAM_TIMETABLE
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN   
    :new.EXAM_ID:= P1_EXAM_TIMETABLE_SEQ.nextval; 
    :new.CREATED_ON:= SYSDATE; 
    :new.CREATED_BY:= nvl(v('APP_USER'), 'SYSTEM'); 
    :new.UPDATED_BY:= NULL; 
    :new.UPDATED_ON:= NULL;
END;
```

Does Any one know where am i missing, please help me to fix this

Comment: Can you post the table structure? The error suggests that you have type issues. Also, what is `v('APP_USER')` ?

Comment: i have created same trigger but this is not working i doubt why it is not working

Comment: It's hard to help you without knowing the table

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it won't work. This is what you're doing:

Table:

```
"CREATED_ON" NUMBER,                 --> number datatype
```

Trigger:

```
:new.CREATED_ON:= SYSDATE;          --> SYSDATE is a function that returns DATE datatype
```

You can't put date into a numeric datatype. What to do? Fix column datatype and change it to `DATE`.

---

```
SQL> create table p1_exam_timetable(
  2    exam_id      number(7,0),
  3    sch_no       number(4,0),
  4    class_code   varchar2(3),
  5    exam_name    varchar2(11),
  6    max_marks    number(3,0),
  7    exam_date    date,
  8    sch_session  varchar2(7),
  9    subject      varchar2(20),
 10    created_by   varchar2(30),
 11    created_on   date,              --> Here! Was NUMBER
 12    updated_by   varchar2(30),
 13    updated_on   number,
 14    constraint p1_exam_timetable_pk primary key(exam_id)
 15      using index enable
 16  )
 17  /

Table created.

SQL> create sequence p1_exam_timetable_seq;

Sequence created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger bi_p1_exam_timetable before
  2    insert on p1_exam_timetable
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.exam_id    := p1_exam_timetable_seq.nextval;
  6    :new.created_on := sysdate;
  7    :new.created_by := nvl(v('APP_USER'), 'SYSTEM');
  8    :new.updated_by := null;
  9    :new.updated_on := null;
 10  end;
 11  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into p1_exam_timetable (exam_id) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from p1_exam_timetable;

   EXAM_ID     SCH_NO CLA EXAM_NAME    MAX_MARKS EXAM_DATE  SCH_SES
---------- ---------- --- ----------- ---------- ---------- -------
SUBJECT              CREATED_BY                     CREATED_ON
-------------------- ------------------------------ ----------
UPDATED_BY                     UPDATED_ON
------------------------------ ----------
         1
                     SYSTEM                         22.02.2021



SQL>
```

---

P.S. When working with Oracle, don't use double quotes, they cause nothing but problems.